# How to draw rectangle and circle in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to draw rectangle on image, its working fine but I want to draw it from the point where the user touches finger, it should consider finger touch as middle point and draw rectangle around it. I tried using drawRect() method and even General Path. This is my code.

```
                GeneralPath pp= new GeneralPath();
                pp.moveTo(currentLine.startX, currentLine.startY-offset / 2);
                pp.lineTo(currentLine.startX, currentLine.startY + offset /2);
                pp.lineTo(currentLine.startX + offset, currentLine.startY + offset /2);
                pp.lineTo(currentLine.startX + offset, currentLine.startY -offset /2);
                pp.lineTo(currentLine.startX, currentLine.startY-offset / 2);

                pp.closePath();

                g.drawShape(pp, stroke);

 //tried even this method
g.drawRect(currentLine.startX, currentLine.startY , currentLine.startX , currentLine.startY, currentLine.girth);
```

Here the current line points are nothing but the co-ordinates of finger touch.

And to draw circle I used this method drawArc() as in code

`// to draw circle
g.drawArc(currentLine.startX, currentLine.startY , currentLine.startX , currentLine.startY, 0, 360);`

But how to change the stroke thickness in this case? And even this I need to draw from centre point when user touch screen.

In both cases, I dont want to drag and draw shapes. Whenever user touch screen the selected image need to be drawn considering the touch as centre point.And the shape shouldn't be drawn outside the image boundary.

Any solution on this would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Always draw the rectangle or shape at 0,0 and then use translate to place it in the screen. It makes the code simpler. So:

```
g.drawRect(0, 0, fourMM, fourMM);
```

Now you want pointer down to determine the X/Y and drag to resize. Just add these:

```
g.translate(pointerInitialX, pointerInitialY);
g.scale(factorW, factorH);
g.drawRect(0, 0, fourMM, fourMM);
g.resetAffine();
```

The reset affine restores the original translate. I would suggest commenting out the scale then working on a ratio formula that "feels" right. This takes some finesse that differs a lot.

Comment: But how do you set stroke thickness for an arc? if you need drawShape() then how do we specify a "circle shape"?

Comment: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/geom/GeneralPath.html#arc-double-double-double-double-double-double-